# Aplicación JAVA instalada en otra pc no permite escribir en la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenos días soy nuevo en el foro. Estoy teniendo un problema que me esta por hacer estallar la cabeza.

Programe en JAVA un sistema de inventario para llevar el control del stock de la empresa donde trabajo, el cual se conecta a una base MySQL de phpmyadmin alojada en el un hosting Ferozo de DonWeb.

Tanto la base de datos como la aplicación funcionan correctamente ya que al ejecutar el código desde el IDE netbeans anda todo perfecto permitiendo ejecutar todos los comandos SQL, desde SELECT hasta DELETE. Lo mismo cuando creo la Build del proyecto y ejecuto el Archivo .jar desde mi PC. Funciona todo correctamente.

El problema esta cuando quiero compartir la aplicación y pasarla a las PC del almacén. Comparto la carpeta con el .jar del proyecto y las librerías. La aplicación arranca correctamente, conecta con la base de datos por que accede a la información alojada en la misma pero no me deja Realizar operaciones de INSERT ni UPDATE. sin embargo si me deja Eliminar filas de las tablas. Mientras que ejecutando el mismo .jar desde mi pc todas las acciones las ejecuta correctamente y no presenta ningún problema.

***Este es el String de conexión:***

```
private static final String USER = "c1901029";                  
private static final String PASSWORD = "*********";        
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://vps-2838525-x.dattaweb.com/c1901029_inv?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
```

***Estas son las Librerias que importo para la gestion y conexion SQL:***
del dirver MySQL connector.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

***ESTE ES UN EJEMPLO DEL METODO INSERT QUE UTILIZO PARA REGISTRAR UN PRODUCTO:***

```
    public int registrarProducto(String codigo, String descripcion, String categoria){
        int res=0;
        try {
            PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO producto (pro_codigo,pro_descripcion,pro_categoria) values (?,?,?)");

            PS.setString(1, codigo);
            PS.setString(2, descripcion);
            PS.setString(3, categoria);
            res = PS.executeUpdate();
            if(res > 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto registrado con éxito.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo registrar el producto.");
            System.err.println("Error al registrar el producto." +e.getMessage());
        } finally{
            PS = null;
            CN.desconectar();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Error capturado con System.out.print(e.getStackTrace())

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isBlank()Z
        at Formularios.Frm_Productos.bt_guardarActionPerformed(Frm_Productos.java:365)
        at Formularios.Frm_Productos.access$500(Frm_Productos.java:20)
        at Formularios.Frm_Productos$6.actionPerformed(Frm_Productos.java:256)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: ¿Y te dice algo al hacer el insert desde la terminal "que no funciona"? Eh, yo haría un `System.out.print(e.getStackTrace())` en ese catch pa no perderme de nada del error que pueda haber...

Comment: Pon lo que te arroja el log cuando haces el getStackTrace

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuesta. Agrege el error capturado por getStackTrace

Comment: Será posible que en donde desarrollaste esto uses Java 11 y en la otra terminal hay Java 8?

Comment: El método isBlank es de Java 11. Es posible que en el servidor u máquina que esté usando la aplicación sea una versión inferior a Java 11

Comment: Exactamente ese es el problema Tiene que ver con la versión de JAVA y el método IsBlank(). Con solo cambiar el método funciona correctamente. En ningún otro momento se me había ocurrido ejecutar el archivo desde CMD para ver la pila del error.  Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!.

Comment: @RoyalUp ponlo como respuesta, así la pueden aceptar y todos saben cómo resolver ésto :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Ponla tú que has respondido primero! :D

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a la ayuda de Alfabravo y RoyalUp encontramos el error.

El problema Tiene que ver con la versión de JAVA y el método IsBlank() ya que el mismo solo esta disponible a partir de la versión 11, mientras que en la pc donde ejecutaba el .jar tenia la versión 8.

Con solo cambiar el método ya funciona correctamente.

Me ayudo el ejecutar el archivo .jar desde el CMD de windows, para poder ver la pila con el error.